# Ubuntu instaled ruby-dev but still can not install gem nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install gem nokogiri by:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20181003-5678-1ub6p51.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
```

I search on google and they said it because there are no ruby-dev. So I install ruby-dev by:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
~$ dpkg -l | grep ruby-dev
ii  ruby-dev:amd64    2:2.3.0+1bbox1~xenial1         
      amd64        Header files for compiling extension modules for Ruby (default version)
```

And it install ruby-dev successfully but still get error before.

Comment: Can you please run this commands: sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri

Comment: @Nezir 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: did you check official nokogiri instructions? http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Comment: also please to run this command: sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What do you get in terminal when you run these commands ruby -v rails -v bundler -v

Comment: ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x86_64-linux]
I have no rails and bundler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the problem you dont have rails installed and also gem bundler.
Can you please install it:

Run in terminal:

```
 gem install bundler
```

and after that:

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: bundler install success but rails failed when install nokogiri

Comment: Okay, lets try to install all of these: sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev

Comment: It missing libruby2.3, I install libruby2.3 and it ok, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

install specific version of ruby

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.5-dev

gem install nokogiri -v 1.8.4 -- --use-system-libraries
```